# merge several dataframes with different column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of 40 dataframes with columns similar to the dataframes as shown below. The reference columns to create a merged dataframe are a and b type columns in each dataframe. I am not able to do it using reduce function as b column is not named similarly in all dataframes. I need to create merge based on a, b type columns. Then retain a type column name for once, and then all b type column names. Is there any possible way to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

# create sample dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b1': [4, 5, 6], 'c1': [7, 8, 9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b2': [4, 5, 6], 'c2': [13, 14, 15]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b3': [4, 5, 9], 'c3': [19, 20, 21]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b4': [1, 5, 6], 'c4': [25, 26, 27]})

# create a list of dataframes
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

# merge dataframes based on common columns
merged_df = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on='a', suffixes=('_left', '_right')), dfs)

# display the merged dataframe
print(merged_df)
```

```
the expected output is as follows:
| a | b1 | c1 | b2 | c2 | b3 | c3 | b4 | c4 |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| 2 | 5 | 8 | 5 | 14 | 5 | 20 | 5 | 26 |
```

Comment: What is your expected output for the given input?

Comment: Why not rename dataframe columns prior to merging? Given the current input something like `df.rename(columns=lambda x: x[0])` will work.

Comment: i am not looking to rename here. I need to retain the columns related to b in the merged dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Since you edited your question, you can use:

```
def merge(left, right):
    return pd.merge(left, right, suffixes=('_left', '_right'),
                    left_on=left.columns[:2].tolist(),
                    right_on=right.columns[:2].tolist())

merged_df = reduce(merge, dfs)
```

The idea is still the same, `merge` using column positions like the two first columns in your example.

Output:

```
>>> merged_df
   a  b1  c1  b2  c2  b3  c3  b4  c4
0  2   5   8   5  14   5  20   5  26
```

---

If your columns are always in the same position (suppose first and second columns), you can use:

```
def merge(left, right):
    left.columns = ['a', 'b'] + left.columns[2:].tolist()
    right.columns = ['a', 'b'] + right.columns[2:].tolist()
    return pd.merge(left, right, on=['a', 'b'],
                    suffixes=('_left', '_right'), how='outer')

merged_df = reduce(merge, dfs)
```

Output:

```
>>> merged_df
   a  b   c1    c2    c3    c4
0  1  4  7.0  13.0  19.0   NaN
1  2  5  8.0  14.0   NaN   NaN
2  3  6  9.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  4  6  NaN  15.0   NaN  27.0
4  3  5  NaN   NaN  20.0  26.0
5  4  9  NaN   NaN  21.0   NaN
6  2  1  NaN   NaN   NaN  25.0
```